# Is Oliver Queen dead?

Tags: arrowverse, arrow

Recently, during the finale of the Arrowverse crossover "Crisis on Infinite Earths", Oliver Queen was shown dying while saving the world from the Anti-Monitor. So is he really dead or he is still alive somewhere?

Comment: See the Arrow finale for details regarding this?

Comment: I think it says a lot about superhero stories that "I just watched this character die, but are they *actually dead?*" is a question people feel the need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

### He's dead

The Monitor took Felicity from 2040 to see Oliver and warns her there is no coming back.  Felicity comments that she didn't expect **the afterlife** to look so much like Oliver's old office, and Oliver says it's a long story but he has all the time in the world to tell it to her.

They are effectively both dead and in the show/universe equivalent of Heaven.